# roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch not working

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I followed the instructions for installing the turtlebot and everything seemed to be working fine!
However, when I try to start the connection with turtlebot I get following output:

```
...
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [24237]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-3]: started with pid [24263]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [24278]
process[mobile_base-5]: started with pid [24283]
process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [24331]
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [24392]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-8]: started with pid [24463]
process[capability_server-9]: started with pid [24503]
process[app_manager-10]: started with pid [24506]
process[master-11]: started with pid [24513]
process[interactions-12]: started with pid [24516]
process[zeroconf/zeroconf-13]: started with pid [24544]
[ INFO] [1436789339.413865208]: Zeroconf: service successfully established [turtlebot][_ros-master._tcp][11311]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bondpy/bondpy.py:114: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, Status)
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bondpy/bondpy.py:114: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, Status)
```

The difference with this output to the instructions is that after the line:
`process[master-11]: started with pid [24513]`
is, that I am not getting an `ERROR: cannot launch node of type...`

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213597/roslaunch-turtlebot_bringup-minimal.launch-not-working/) by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-13**:
Can you please format console copy/pastes with the *Preformatted text* button from the toolbar? It's the one with `101010` on it. Otherwise this is unreadable. Thanks.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-13**:
Have you change anything in the code or creating your own python nodes? The problem is relatively simple. Somewhere a publisher is being created something like `pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String)` but it has to contain also queue_size=10 or any other number in the parameters.

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-13**:
thanks for the help! @gvdhoorn: yes I will the next time, sorry. There seemed to be a problem with the Kobuki base driver but now it is working. Thanks!

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-13**:
Could you please reply to your own answer giving a bit more detail on what failed and did you fix it? It could be useful for other users.

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2015-07-17**:
@gvdhoorn
Could you let me know detailedly how you solved this problem? I met the same one. Thanks very much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-17**:
I did not solve this (it was also not my question, but @Salocin808's). Did you install the driver for the base, as @Salocin808 mentioned in his answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the late reply! The solution was simple because I simply forgot to install the driver for the Kobuki base:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Kobuki%20Base

---

Originally posted by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) with karma: 33 on 2015-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3